# Load assemblies and relative dependencies on .NET Core 3.1 : multiple problems with Microsoft.Data.Sqlclient

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, .net-core

it's a lot of time that I didn't program with .NET framework, and probably something change in the meanwhile, but I'm no more able to load an assembly at runtime (a DLL containing a AspNetCore Mvc ControllerBase) inside an AspNetCore Host application.

Or, more precisely, all is working fine if i've got no dependencies inside the ControllerBase DLL project. I createa a simple text code to execute a stored procedure using Microsoft.Data.Sqlclient (version 5.0.0 that's compatible with framework NetCore 3.1 that I'm using).

Then, in the host Startup.cs, 'ive got:

```
        private IEnumerable<Assembly> LoadControllerAssemblies(string controllerPath)
        {
            
            AssemblyLoadContext.Default.Resolving += (context, name) => {
                string assemblyPath = $"{controllerPath}\\dep\\{name.Name}.dll";
                if (assemblyPath != null)
                    return context.LoadFromAssemblyPath(assemblyPath);
                return null;
            };
            

            var assemblies = new List<Assembly>();
            //To get the location the assembly normally resides on disk or the install directory
            string path = System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().CodeBase;

            //once you have the path you get the directory with:
            var directory = Path.Combine(System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(path), controllerPath).Replace("file:\\", @"");

            // Carica tutti i file DLL nella cartella specificata
            var dllFiles = Directory.GetFiles(directory, "*.dll");
            foreach (var dllFile in dllFiles)
            {
                try
                {
                    // Carica l'assembly con l'API AssemblyLoadContext
                    var assembly = AssemblyLoadContext.Default.LoadFromAssemblyPath(dllFile);
                    assemblies.Add(assembly);
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
//                    _logger.LogError(ex, $"Errore durante il caricamento dell'assembly {dllFile}");
                }
            }

            //var assemblyPath = Path.Combine(System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(path), controllerPath, "dep", "Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.dll").Replace("file:\\", @"");
            //var assemblyDep = AssemblyLoadContext.Default.LoadFromAssemblyPath(assemblyPath);

            return assemblies;
        }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            //string path = System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location;
            services.AddHttpContextAccessor();


            services.AddMvc().SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_3_0);

            var controllerAssemblies = LoadControllerAssemblies("Controllers");

            // Registra i controller di API con il framework DI
            foreach (var assembly in controllerAssemblies)
            {

                services.AddMvc()
                  .AddApplicationPart(assembly).AddControllersAsServices();
            }
            
            
            services.AddHttpClient("apiClient", client =>
            {
                client.BaseAddress = new Uri(Globals.SL_URI);
            }).ConfigurePrimaryHttpMessageHandler(() =>
            {
                var handler = new HttpClientHandler();
                handler.ServerCertificateCustomValidationCallback = (message, certificate, chain, errors) => true;
                return handler;
            });



            services.AddRouting();

            //services.AddHostedService<ControllerLoader>();
        }
```

I tried a lot of different things but there's always a problem: with the code posted here I'm trying to load assembly dependencies from a folder in which I put Microsoft.Data.Sqlclient but i've got always:

```
System.Reflection.ReflectionTypeLoadException
  HResult=0x80131602
  Message=Unable to load one or more of the requested types.
**Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Data.SqlClient, Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=23ec7fc2d6eaa4a5'. The parameter is incorrect.** (0x80070057 (E_INVALIDARG))
  Source=System.Private.CoreLib
  StackTrace:
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeModule.GetTypes(RuntimeModule module)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.get_DefinedTypes()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ApplicationParts.AssemblyPart.get_Types()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Controllers.ControllerFeatureProvider.PopulateFeature(IEnumerable`1 parts, ControllerFeature feature)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ApplicationParts.ApplicationPartManager.PopulateFeature[TFeature](TFeature feature)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.MvcCoreMvcBuilderExtensions.AddControllersAsServices(IMvcBuilder builder)
   at LpOneLoginAPI.Startup.ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services) in C:\Users\me\source\repos\LoginModule\LoginModule\Startup.cs:line 85
   at System.RuntimeMethodHandle.InvokeMethod(Object target, Object[] arguments, Signature sig, Boolean constructor, Boolean wrapExceptions)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.Invoke(Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.ConfigureServicesBuilder.InvokeCore(Object instance, IServiceCollection services)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.ConfigureServicesBuilder.<>c__DisplayClass9_0.<Invoke>g__Startup|0(IServiceCollection serviceCollection)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.ConfigureServicesBuilder.Invoke(Object instance, IServiceCollection services)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.ConfigureServicesBuilder.<>c__DisplayClass8_0.<Build>b__0(IServiceCollection services)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.GenericWebHostBuilder.UseStartup(Type startupType, HostBuilderContext context, IServiceCollection services)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.GenericWebHostBuilder.<>c__DisplayClass12_0.<UseStartup>b__0(HostBuilderContext context, IServiceCollection services)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.HostBuilder.CreateServiceProvider()
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.HostBuilder.Build()
   at LoginModule.Program.Main(String[] args) in C:\Users\me\source\repos\LoginModule\LoginModule\Program.cs:line 27
```

I tried to load everything putting all dependencies in the same folder than my ControllerBase DLL. In this everything start, but when I call the API inside the container I've got:

Microsoft.Data.SqlClient is not supported on this platform.

The only way I found to make it works was importing in the Host main program the Microsoft.Data.Sqlclient dependency (as the dll controllerbase), but I don't want to do so because obviously the idea is tha DLL modules with controllers could be developed by anyone without modifiy the host program.

I also do a lot of other test, but everything failed.

Where I wrong? There's something wrong with this version o f the framework (quite old, I know, but at the moment al the main project is developed with .NETCore 3.1) ?

What else can I try?

Comment: .NET Core 3.1 is now completely out of support. Consider upgrading to v6 or v7. Or recompile that DLL to use System.Data.SqlClient

Comment: Wasn't this the solution where you had to run some installer so you couldn't just copy dlls and it worked?

Comment: @Charlieface just tried it, same scenario: System.Data.SqlClient is not supported on this platform if loaded directly or, in case of resolving dependencies, "The parameter is incorrect.". Totally the same, it's not something tied to Microsodt.Data.Sqlclient but something else.

Comment: @ThomasKoelle I don't understand what you mean, sorry.

Comment: @Hammeronthenet I am pretty sure some of the stuff you did automatically happens when you install via either the NuGet GUI in Visual Studio, or the Package Manager Console.

Answer (score 0):

That's not properly an answer, but after a lot of tests with System.Data.SqlClient I just found some conclusion that probably works also for Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.

1. In the Controller DLL application, into .csproj, inside PropertyGroup, I put the flag:

true

2. Recompiling the solution, I've got a lot of DLL inside the main project bin folder, and also a subdir named "runtime"
3. Inside the "host" bin project, in "controller" folder (the subdir where I put my DLL) I put not only the main DLL but also sni.dll and System.Data.SqlClient.dll.
   These two DLL are taken from inside the "runtime" folder. "sni.dll" is inside win-x64 and "System.Data.SqlClient.dll" (please note that this is a different dll comapred to the one obtained directly during compile) is took from runtimes/win directory.
4. Delete on host application the part inherent AssemblyLoadContext.Default.Resolving (the event).

In this way all work fine.

But now I'm really confused on which could be best practises to create this kind of application. imho this solution is very botched and surely there's a better way to proceed